# http://IP:3306 reveals potential exploit?

Tags: mysql

A security audit was performed on my network and the auditor flagged an issue which he feels is a high-level threat regarding our MySQL 5.7.24 installation on an IIS server.

When browsing to `http://%myIP%:3306` the visitor receives the following message:

```
[���5.7.24-log�C���.m[aUg&$�ÿ÷�€����������p;}fQ^Z?Ia�mysql_native_password�!��ÿ„#08S01Got packets out of order
```

The auditor feels that MySQL is possibly revealing a user name or password in this response.

I doubt this is the case, but wanted to get responses from the experts.

Also, is this (what appears to be a login prompt) necessary? Is there a way to turn this response off?

Comment: This really isn't a programming question, and security audit questions don't fit here. It's possible that a security-related question would fit on  dba.stackexchange.com. That said: MySQL doesn't reveal a name or password because you connect to its port. And it's also not a browsable port (that is, there is no web server listening on 3306).

Comment: "which he feels is a high-level threat" -- He should either know it or be able to research it. Otherwise you should probably hire another guy who knows what he's doing...

Comment: You should also inform your auditor that MySQL doesn't store its passwords as plaintext, and cannot reveal passwords.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because https://security.stackexchange.com/ probably has more expertise on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

Some things:

1. Using unencrypted rather than TLS-encrypted MySQL connections is a far bigger vulnerability than MySQL responding with error gibberish when you hit it like it's a web server. Badguys can sniff your customer data.
2. You should consider firewalling your MySQL instances so they can only be hit from the machines needing their services. If this audit probe comes from the public network, this is definitely something you **must remediate**. "True positive."
3. MySQL here announces its available authentication method (`mysql_native_password`). It also indicates its confusion upon receiving HTTP protocol data rather than MySQL protocol. `packets out of order`. So it is functioning as designed and revealing nothing except that it is MySQL. "False positive."
4. If this auditor insists this is still a problem after you explain it, then you should consider switching to TLS connections to your MySQL instances.

For what it's worth, I've never seen an auditor who knew much about protocols other than HTTP/S.